# How to handle errors in plack delayed response

Tags: perl, plack

Tried to handle errors in delayed response.

Every time i send [200, [ 'Content-Type', 'application/json' ]
and got error before flushing the other things like that

$w->write("MyData");

$w->close();

i've got a warning in stdout and error in stderr, but page keeps loading.

it'll be loading until i stop app or stop page loading by hand.

how i can stop loading page in code or how to correctly handle errors in such apps where i use delayed response?

Perl version 5.24
Kelp version 1.02
Running Plack with Corona.

We're handling error throwing Exception::Class.
Catching errors with Try::Tiny.

Also tried eval and others things, but it doesn't work.
But changed Try::Tiny ->  TryCatc and return if got any error, but 
i need write return for every catch block, it looks very bad

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Kelp::Less;
get '/hello' => sub  {
    return sub {
        my $res = shift;
        my $w = $res->([200, [ 'Content-Type', 'application/json' ]]);
        my $data = 10 / 0;
        $w->write("MyData");
        $w->close();
    }
};
run;
```

I'm looking for correct error handling,
do i need try{} catch{}; on every code that might fail?

Thanks @ikegami for answer, but page still loading after tries with Object::Destoyer and Sub::ScopeFinalizer. As i understand $w(writer) doesn't cause page loading. After exiting scope, $w comes undef then there's nothing to close, here is code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Object::Destroyer;
use Kelp::Less;
get '/hello' => sub  {
    return sub {
        my $res = shift;

        my $w = $res->([200, [ 'Content-Type', 'application/json' ]]);
        my $g = Object::Destroyer->new( sub { $w->close if $w } );
        my $zzz = 1 / 0;
        $w->write("DATA");
        $w->close();
    }
};
run;
```

so i've come up with that solution, what do you think?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Try::Tiny;
use Object::Destroyer;
use Kelp::Less;
get '/hello' => sub  {
    return sub {
        my $res = shift;

        my $w = $res->([200, [ 'Content-Type', 'application/json' ]]);
        my $g = Object::Destroyer->new( sub { $w->close if $w; } );
        my $ans = try {                                                                   
            my $zzz = 1 / 0;                                                              
        }                                                                                 
        catch {
            print $_;                                                                   
            return;                                                                       
        };                                                                                
        return unless $ans;

        $w->write("DATA");
        $w->close();
    }
};
run;
```

Comment: Try::Tiny just uses `eval`, so your claims that it doesn't work with `eval` and it does work with Try::Tiny are incongruent

Comment: How about the following: `use Sub::ScopeFinalizer qw( scope_finalize ); my $w; my $guard = scope_finalize { $w->close if $w }; $w = $res->(...); ...;`

Comment: Or the simpler but more magical: `use Object::Destroyer; my $w = Object::Destroyer->new( $res->(...), 'close' ); ...;`

Comment: sorry, i was busy on the weekend.
i tried it, but neither of them didn't help.
Sub::ScopeFinalizer returns:
{`
Can't call method "scope_finalizer" on an undefined value at
}
Object::Destroyer returns
{
Object::Destroyer requires that Plack::Util::Prototype has a close method
`}

Comment: lol, can't get along with code formatting. can't edit after 5mins.
`{ Sub::ScopeFinalizer returns:
Can't call method "scope_finalizer" on an undefined value at ...} Object::Destroyer returns Object::Destroyer requires that Plack::Util::Prototype has a close method 
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve this problem with wrapping app with

```
Plack::Middleware::HTTPExceptions
```